# How do you know if a home with brick veneer is masonry or frame?

Tags: brick, masonry, frame, veneer

How do you know if a home with brick veneer is masonry or frame?

[https://www.bing.com/maps?osid=d8f9b72f-6595-407c-a618-2c14fbb501d5&cp=30.69822~-87.076315&lvl=19&dir=365.8949&pi=0.57376033&style=x&mo=z.2.48&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027](https://www.bing.com/maps?osid=d8f9b72f-6595-407c-a618-2c14fbb501d5&cp=30.69822%7E-87.076315&lvl=19&dir=365.8949&pi=0.57376033&style=x&mo=z.2.48&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027)

Comment: How do you know it's brick veneer?

Comment: It would make everyone's life easier if you simply took a picture of your house and shared it here instead of pasting a search engine link.

Comment: Look for repeating bricks / pattern

Comment: Is there a frame wall with gypsum board on the interior? Can you look in the attic to see if there is a frame wall?

Comment: According to the [country records](https://srcpa.gov/Parcel/Index2?parcel=08-2N-28-5435-00000-0170), the exterior walls are "BRICK", while the interior walls are "DRYWALL". To me that implies 'real' masonry walls for the exterior, rather than a thin brick-lookalike veneer, but the only way to be certain would be to go and look at the walls close-up.

Comment: I would think exterior wall thickness would give a clue, unless it is framed with 2x6s, but that would be more common way up north, not in Florida. Oh, and @Tetsujin "How do you know it's brick veneer?" Does it look and feel like brick, and was it built in the US after WW2? Then its brick veneer.

Answer (score 2):

Look for tell-tale signs.

- Can you see or even measure the thickness of an exterior wall, perhaps by looking at the jamb of an open door or window? If the width of a door's jamb (not including the trim woodwork on either side) is about 4.5 inches then the wall is probably 2x4 stick frame. A much wider door jamb would be likely when the wall is masonry.
- Is there an unfinished basement or crawl space? Look at the detail where the ground-level floor attaches to the foundation. If the walls are masonry the floor joists will be attached with some manner of hangers; if the walls are stick frame the floor joists are most likely to rest on top of the foundation wall.

Answer (score 0):

bang on the wall inside, if it feels soft like drywall and sounds hollow it's framed. if it silent except the sound of the impact and feels solid it's masonry.

A single floor dwelling with floor a slab floor level to the ground. is probably framed with a veneer. but the image provided isn't clear enough to make out the crib patter used in the brickwork.